What does "|" mean?
I've searched online but somehow I didn't find an answer to that question.
what does the | sign means?
I've seen it used to separate commands but how does it differ than the other signs?
Thanks!
Boker

It's the pipe symbol. The answer you are looking for is explained in this superuser post.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/piping-in-unix-or-linux/

See also What are the shell's control and redirection operators?
